# Type script error "Data is possibly null"

Tags: typescript, types

Typescript is showing error in the following code
'data' is possibly 'null'.
and it does not matter how many checks I add the Typescript is stuck at this error. How to solve ?

```
if (data != null && data?.hasOwnProperty("term_id")) {
           return data.term_id;
        }
```

Comment: Try return `data!.term_id;`.

Here `data!` tells TypeScript to treat data as non-null within the scope of the if block.

Comment: Still the same error :  Type error: Object is possibly 'null'.
  125 |         if (data !== null && typeof data === "object") {
> 126 |             return data!.term_id;

Comment: Could you please share the type that `data` is defined as?

Comment: usually, this should work, `if(data?.term_id)`

Comment: and if still doesn't, you can revert the condition and work around other scenarios.
i.e: `if(!data) return other stuff else 'data.term_id'`

Comment: @NicholasTower data is a query return from a database. https://prnt.sc/YJjG85pJYMaq

Comment: @HusnainTariq tried that https://prnt.sc/VYCxABuM1dfo

Comment: @Mr.Vibe just checked your code, you should give 'data' a type i.e: `var {data }: {data: {term_id?: string}} `or something like that so that TS knows that this `term_id` could be expected

Comment: @Husnain Tariq : Yes this is the correct answer.